# What is the proper way to handle user manipulated form data?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

Quick overview:
I have a pilot and ship entities. One pilot can have few ships but only one can be active at a time.
Now, let's say a pilot wants to activate another ship. In this case a form containing ship id is submitted and I have to display a message with the result (activated or not activated).
Assuming that user changed the ship id in html (to a non existing one or a ship of another user), which of these two possibilities is more "appropriate"?

**Option 1:**
Perform a check in a service layer function responsible for activating the ship and throw an exception if something is wrong. The exception is then handled by a controller and appropriate message is added to the model.

**Option 2:**
Perform a validation inside the controller and call service layer function that activates the ship only if the data is correct.
I think second option seems better at the beginning but the downside is I would have to make two exact database queries to find the ship. One in a controller for validation purposes and then another one in service layer to actually activate it. Service method is @Transactional so if I pass the controller found ship as an argument, Hibernate retrieves it from the database anyway so for now I went with the option 1 to avoid repeating database calls because that just seems bad.
I'm still learning so I'd love to hear what more experienced users have to say in this case.  If there's a better way to do it, I'm also open to suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't expose your database ID's to end user. In the Controller, make a list, and on the form, iterate the list and use the iteration number (index) from the list.

Comment: So for example, if user has 3 ships of ids: 5,8,11 I should create a list and add it's indexes to a html form so 1 would represent 5, 2 -> 8 and 3 -> 11. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes. Then you just validate the returned index from the form against the list.

Comment: I have a little problem with this method. Let's say I populated the list with ships in GET controller, added the list to the model, everything is fine. However, how do I retrieve this list in POST controller? After some googling I found that @SessionAttributes could be used to achieve that. The question is: Is there any better way? Also, I guess that session attributes are kept on server so user doesn't have access to them thus it's safe to put ID's in there. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: Also your list could be wrong if the user builds a new ship, then goes back to a previous page. @Stewart the database IDs would only be exposed to the view layer, not the end user; is that not OK?

Comment: Wouldn't going back call GET controller again and repopulate the list? Also the way it is done now, when you click "view source" you can see database ID's as values in hidden fields so I'd really like to make this list method work :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your business logic should be in an entity or in a service class, or using something like Hibernate Validator. Spring isn't very DDD, so a service is the normal route.

Keep as little logic in the controllers as possible. This makes your models more useful if you switch to a different type of user interface, like a REST API.

It's okay to expose your database keys by the way, as long as you are using something like Spring Security ACL to not expose data to the wrong users.

Comment: I'm not using ACL but after quick googling I will definitely learn more about it once I have some spare time. Thanks for mentioning it. Meanwhile, if I perform a validation on the server side, is it still ok to expose the ids? For example: user changes pilot id, server checks if the ship of given id belongs to user, if yes continue, if not throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

1. GET Controller builds a `List` from database, which it stores in session, and passes to view.
2. View iterates and displays list. HTML form references each item by its list index (starting at `0`)
3. POST Controller validates returned form data against session list. If invalid, form is re-displayed with same list. If valid, the database ID of the chosen item will be one of the datums in the list, the list is removed from session, and flow continues ...

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I had in mind. The thing is, if user fires the GET controller but does not submit the form, the list will be kept in the session. Will there be any memory issues if you multiply it by the number of controllers storing session attributes?

Comment: That's a calculation you'll have to make yourself. Default session timeout is often 30 mins. How many users? How big is each item in memory? Are they lazy loaded from the database? Is Hibernate using caching? If it's a real problem, maybe consider implementing a "lite" version of the item, or using something from `java.lang.ref` or implement a Guava `Supplier`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wish I could accept more than one answer because both are good depending on the situation. I like this approach but I've been told to avoid session attributes whenever possible so I'm just gonna make sure that users can only view their own content. The least I can do is upvote. Thanks again.